# PHP to Java - Sockets

Tags: java, php, sockets

I am trying to communicate from php to java using sockets. I have the following java code:

```
private static ServerSocket socket;

private static Socket connection;
private static String command       = new String();
private static String responseStr   = new String();

private static int port = 2500;

public static void main(String args[])  {
    System.out.println("Server is running.");

    try  {
        socket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while (true)  {
            connection = socket.accept();

            InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream response = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

            command = input.readLine();
            response.writeBytes(responseStr);
            response.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e)  {
        System.out.println("Fail!: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://192.168.0.10:2500", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
        fwrite($conn, 'The local time is ' . date('n/j/Y g:i a') . "\n");
        fclose($conn);
    }
    fclose($socket);
}
```

I start the java app, which starts fine, When I run the php, I get the following error:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (0)
```

I have searched Google and have tried all the solutions I could find although nothing has worked. I have restarted both machines and disabled the firewall, neither worked.

I am not sure where to go from here.

---

[update from comment:]

192.168.0.10 is the machine with the java app and web server on it. I am connecting from another machine 192.168.0.7

Comment: 192.168.0.10 is the IP address of which machine?

Comment: 192.168.0.10 is the machine with the java app and web server on it. I am connecting from another machine 192.168.0.7

Comment: This will not solve your current issue, but have you considered using the AMQP messaging protocol to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can only can create a socket on the machine were the code is running on.

So if the PHP code is run on 192.168.0.7, then do:

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://192.168.0.7:2500", $errno, $errstr);
```